# Loading a runtime dynamically loaded angular module into an angular application

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

We are attempting to do something in our team with Angular4 that is
not properly documented.

Something along the lines of what is described here -

---

https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/1358#issuecomment-248890159

https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/5zji6j/anyone_know_if_its_possible_to_dynamically_load/

---

We are using Angular CLI and webpack and we are having trouble getting
SystemJsNgModuleLoader to load a remote module served over HTTP/HTTPS.
The issues are as follows

1. How to pre-compile a single module in a format recognized by the loader?
2. Loader does not appear to be making HTTP calls and fails
   prematurely with module not found error.

We are looking for a reasonable example of getting the loader to
understand a "precompiled" module. Let me know if you can help with
this.

Just to give a slightly bigger picture - We are building a plugin like framework where the parent application will be in Angular and the plugin application will also be an Angular module but parent application and the plugin application are hosted in different domains and parent does not want to have compile time awareness of the child plugin.

There are a whole bunch of articles on this but none that answers comprehensively using Angular CLI and webpack.